# Getting string from WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, string

I want to get the string generated by the WCF service, both synchronously and asynchronously. I know that with the bitmap, for instance, it's a piece of cake - you can add the event handler to BitmapImage on e.g. IsDownloaded or something. How about strings? How can I achieve that? Assume that I want to use URi for calling the WCF service.

What is the best approach for that?

Thanks in advance for the reply!

Cheers

Comment: Can you provide a little more  information?  What string are you talking about?  Can you post your servicecontract and/or datacontract?

Comment: I think of a simple string, passing back and forth, say:

[OperationContract]
void f(string a);
[OperationContract]
string f2();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the [Default Message Contract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751464(v=VS.90).aspx) sample from MSDN.

Comment: I will take a glance at that stuff